# How to add "not found" result on search data on laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

Is there a way to add result "not found" if my data is not in the database ?

In my search button I want to add a result that: if the search doesn't conclude the data inside the defined form, the search must output `data not found`...

The search is working...

Here is my controller

**pegawaicontroller.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Pegawai;


class pegawaicontroller extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $pegawais = Pegawai::orderBy('id', 'ASC')->paginate(5);
        return view('pegawai.index', compact('pegawais')); 
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('pegawai.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'kategori' => 'required',
            'jabatan' => 'required',
            'nama_pegawai' => 'required',
            'alamat' => 'required',
            'gambar_pegawai' => 'required'
            ]);
            
            // upload file
            $filename = time() . '.png';
            $request->file('gambar_pegawai')->storeAs('public/images', $filename);

            $pegawai = new Pegawai;
            $pegawai->kategori = $request->input('kategori');
            $pegawai->jabatan = $request->input('jabatan');
            $pegawai->nama_pegawai = $request->input('nama_pegawai');
            $pegawai->alamat = $request->input('alamat');
            $pegawai->gambar_pegawai = $filename;
            $pegawai->save();
            // $pegawai = Pegawai::create($request->all()); 
            return redirect()->route('pegawai.index')->with('message','Data berhasil dibuat!'); 
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $pegawai = Pegawai::findOrFail($id);
        return view('pegawai.show', compact('pegawai'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $pegawai = Pegawai::findOrFail($id);
        return view('pegawai.edit', compact('pegawai')); 
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'kategori' => 'required',
            'jabatan' => 'required',
            'nama_pegawai' => 'required',
            'alamat' => 'required',
            'gambar_pegawai' => 'required'
            ]);
            
            // script delete tapii gagal
            // if ($request->produk()->gambar_pegawai){
            //     Storage::delete('images/' . $request->produk()->gambar_pegawai);
            // }

            // update file
            $filename = time() . '.png';
            $request->file('gambar_pegawai')->storeAs('public/images', $filename);

            $pegawai = Pegawai::find($id);
            $pegawai->kategori = $request->input('kategori');
            $pegawai->jabatan = $request->input('jabatan');
            $pegawai->nama_pegawai = $request->input('nama_pegawai');
            $pegawai->alamat = $request->input('alamat');
            $pegawai->gambar_pegawai = $filename;
            $pegawai->save();

            // $pegawai = Pegawai::findOrFail($id)->update($request->all());
            return redirect()->route('pegawai.index')->with('message', 'Data berhasil diubah!'); 
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $pegawai = Pegawai::findOrFail($id)->delete();
        return redirect()->route('pegawai.index')->with('message', 'Data berhasil dihapus!');
    }

public function search(Request $request)
{
    $q = $request->input('searchpegawai');
    $pegawais = Pegawai::where('nama_pegawai', 'LIKE', '%'.$q.'%')
    ->orWhere('alamat', 'LIKE', '%'.$q.'%')
    ->paginate(5);


    return view('pegawai.index')->with('pegawais', $pegawais)->with('query', $q);
    }
}
```

Here Is The Index blade where the search function are...

**index.blade.php**

```
@extends('template.adminlte')

@section('content')
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <div class="content-header">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-2">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h1 class="m-0 text-dark">Menu Pegawai</h1>
          </div><!-- /.col -->
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
              <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li class="breadcrumb-item active">pegawai</li>
            </ol>
          </div><!-- /.col -->
        </div><!-- /.row -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </div>

 <a href="{{ route('pegawai.create') }}" class="btn btn-info btnsm float-left">
 <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"> Tambah Pegawai</i>
 </a><br><br>

    <form class="form-inline ml-3 float-sm-right">
    <form action="searchpegawai" method="GET" role="Search" class="form-inline ml-3">
      <div class="input-group input-group-sm float-sm-right">
        <input class="form-control form-control-navbar float-sm-right" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" name=searchpegawai>
        <div class="input-group-append float-sm-right">
          <button class="btn btn-navbar" type="submit">
            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>

 


 @if ($message = Session::get('message'))
    <div class="alert alert-success martop-sm">
        <p>{{ $message }}</p>
    </div>
 @endif
    <table class="table martop-sm">
    <thead> 
        <th>No</th>
        <!-- <th>ID</th> -->
        <th>Kategori</th>
        <th>Jabatan Pegawai</th>
        <th>Nama pegawai</th>
        <th>Alamat</th>
        <th>Foto Pegawai</th>
        <th>Aksi</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
 @foreach ($pegawais as $key => $pegawai)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $pegawais->firstItem() + $key }}</td>
        <!-- <td>{{ $pegawai->id }}</td> -->
        <td><a href="{{ route('pegawai.show', $pegawai->id)}}">{{ $pegawai->kategori }}</a></td>
        <td><a href="{{ route('pegawai.show', $pegawai->id)}}">{{ $pegawai->jabatan }}</a></td>
        <td><a href="{{ route('pegawai.show', $pegawai->id)}}">{{ $pegawai->nama_pegawai }}</a></td>
        <td><a href="{{ route('pegawai.show', $pegawai->id)}}">{{ $pegawai->alamat }}</a></td>
        <td><a href="{{ route('pegawai.show', $pegawai->id)}}"><img src="{{ asset('storage/images/' . $pegawai->gambar_pegawai) }}" alt="" width="100"></a></td>
        <td>
        <form action="{{ route('pegawai.destroy', $pegawai->id) }}" method="post"> 
        {{csrf_field()}} {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
            <a href="{{ route('pegawai.edit', $pegawai->id) }}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Ubah</a>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="return confirm('Apakah anda yakin ingin menghapusnya?');">Hapus</button>
        </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
 @endforeach
    </tbody>
    </table>
    {{ $pegawais -> links() }}
    </div>
    </section>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Comment: do you want to show extra <tr> in case if you don't have search result?

Comment: yes sir do you have any ideas ?. i appreciate it

Comment: use forelse of laravel blade syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `forelse` in blade

```php
@forelse($pegawais as $key => $pegawai)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $pegawais->firstItem() + $key }}</td>
        <!-- <td>{{ $pegawai->id }}</td> -->
        <td><a href="{{ route('pegawai.show', $pegawai->id)}}">{{ $pegawai->kategori }}</a></td>
        <td><a href="{{ route('pegawai.show', $pegawai->id)}}">{{ $pegawai->jabatan }}</a></td>
        <td><a href="{{ route('pegawai.show', $pegawai->id)}}">{{ $pegawai->nama_pegawai }}</a></td>
        <td><a href="{{ route('pegawai.show', $pegawai->id)}}">{{ $pegawai->alamat }}</a></td>
        <td><a href="{{ route('pegawai.show', $pegawai->id)}}"><img src="{{ asset('storage/images/' . $pegawai->gambar_pegawai) }}" alt="" width="100"></a></td>
        <td>
        <form action="{{ route('pegawai.destroy', $pegawai->id) }}" method="post"> 
        {{csrf_field()}} {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
            <a href="{{ route('pegawai.edit', $pegawai->id) }}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Ubah</a>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="return confirm('Apakah anda yakin ingin menghapusnya?');">Hapus</button>
        </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
@empty
    <tr><td align="center" >Result not found.</td></tr>
@endforelse
```

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#loops

Comment: btw how do I add the notification under the table ? it add the notification  on top of the table form.

Comment: what `notification` ?

Comment: The result not found one... I want to put it ubder the table...

Comment: @Asterisk i updated my code now it will come under the table

Comment: Thanks mate :D I truly appreciate it :)

Comment: Thanks mate :D I truly appreciate it :)